# A conical tent is $8$ $m$ high and the radius of its base is $6$ $m$.

Tags: geometry

A conical tent is $8$ $m$ high and the radius of its base is $6$ m. Find

(i) Slant height of the tent

(ii) Cost of the canvas required to make the tent, if the cost of $1$ $m^2$ canvas is $\$70$.

What I've tried so far,

Height=$8$ $m$

Radius=$6$ $m$

Slant height=$\sqrt{r^2 + h^2}
=10$ $m$

Comment: I don't understand, why did you take height of 8m and radius 6m is in the question they say 10m high and radius 24m??

Comment: I am sorry! That was a typo. I have corrected my mistake.

Comment: Do you know the formula to have the surface of the cone? With the given data and what you have found this is straightforward...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets start by deriving the Surface area of a cone ignoring the base

[image: Cone]

Let the height be $h$

We can see by Pythagoras that the slant height $s = \sqrt{h^2+r^2}$

The shape of the material would, when flattened out look like this

[image]

Which we can see could be cut from a circle of radius $s$

We know the formula for the area of a circle and we know what proportion of the circle we need

Surface Area $A = \pi \cdot s^2 \cdot \dfrac{2 \cdot \pi \cdot r}{2 \cdot \pi \cdot s} = \pi \cdot s \cdot r$

I'll leave it as an exercise to enter from here all you need to do is multiply the area by the cost of the canvas to finish.